# What is the best way to merge an array of arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, ajax

I have an array I am posting through an Ajax call and trying to compare it with the original array. Bottom line is I will use an `array_diff()` to compare them in the end. But my problem is I can't quite get the arrays formed in the same way. `$originalArray` comes from functions that check a checkbox if it's in the database. Now when a user clicks the button on the form it will send an array of the checkbox id's through an Ajax call resulting in `$postArray`.

Here is an example:

```
$postArray = array(3){ 
        [55555]=>string(2)"on" 
        [66666]=>string(2)"on" 
        [77777]=>string(2)"on" 
}
```

```
$originalArray = 
    array(1){ ["appid"]=>string(5) "55555"}, 
    array(1){ ["appid"]=>string(5) "66666"}, 
    array(1){ ["appid"]=>string(5) "77777"}
```

I want to essentially make the `$originalArray` all into one array similar to `$postArray`. Doing an `array_merge($originalArray)` will make an array of an array, which isn't quite right either. Any help is appreciated. Bear with me as I am relatively new to coding and new to Stack Overflow. If you need more information I will gladly do what I can.

Comment: Hi, show us what you have written, and what it generates. Then tell us whats wrong with what it does and what you actually want the resul to look like

Answer (score 4):

You can use `array_combine()` to create an associative array from an array of keys and an array of values.

Use `array_column()` to get all the `appid` values from `$originalArray`.

```
array_combine(array_column($originalArray "appid"), array_fill(0, count($originalArray), "on"));
```

Answer (score 1):

A combination of `array_fill_keys()` to create an array with a specific set of key values and `array_column()` to extract the appid...

```
$postArray = array_fill_keys(array_column($originalArray,"appid"), "on");
```